# RequireJS: Script Error for "express" and "cors", but not sure how to fix it

Tags: javascript, express, requirejs, require

Stack Trace:
require.js:5 (makeError)
require.js:5 (onScriptError)

I am new to using RequireJS, and have no idea how to fix this after spending a couple hours on it.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Here's my code involving require:

```
require.config({
        nodeRequire: require
    });

    require(['express', 'cors'],
        function (express, cors) {
            const app = express()

            app.options('*', cors())

            app.get('/with-cors', cors(), (req, res, next) => {
                res.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
                res.send(params);
            })
        });
```

Comment: Please provide as many details as you can. First of all, we need an exact error from the developer tools console

Comment: Are you trying to run this code in the browser?  Because, if so, you can't run express and cors in the browser.  Those run on a nodejs server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there needs to be a bit more context, but based on what you've included, it looks like you're overwriting node's `require` with requirejs's `require`, i.e.:

```
var require = require('requirejs');
```

This of course, being based on the fact that you're calling `require.config` and passing `require` as `nodeRequire`.

Based on the [example documented here](https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#usage), it looks this should do the trick:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require // Note that this is passing in node's require
                         // not requirejs's require
});

requirejs(['express', 'cors'],
    function(express, cors) {
        ...
    }
);
```